# how to set style to table row with inline javascript if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set background color to ash if one of the variable value is 1 else row background color would be white

But the thing is when the variable value is 1 then row has been added but not the contents. If the variable value is 0 all is working as expected

I have tried the following code:

```js
function insertRow(value){
  $('#invoiceTable').append(
    value === 1 ? '<tr style="background-color: #ccc8cb">' : '<tr>'+
      '<td> category </td>' +
      '<td> material </td>' +
      '<td> ups </td>' +
    '</tr>'
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="invoiceTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover" >
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Material</th>
          <th>ups</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
 
<input type=button value='insert ash row' onclick='insertRow(1)'/>
 
<input type=button value='insert white row' onclick='insertRow(0)'/>
```

Please point what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting `()` around `value === 1 ? '<tr style="background-color:ash">' : '<tr>'` solves the issue:

```
(value === 1 ? '<tr style="background-color:ash">' : '<tr>')
```

What your code is doing is the following, if the `value === 1` then insert `'<tr style="background-color:ash">'` otherwise insert this:

```
'<tr>'+
      '<td> category </td>' +
      '<td> material </td>' +
      '<td> ups </td>' +
    '</tr>'
```

So putting brackets around it will make sure it uses `'<tr style="background-color:ash">'` or `'<tr>'` and after that it will insert the table with your data.

Comment: I've updated the answer to describe why it happens, I hope it's clear

Comment: @NuOneTAttygalle because your current code thinks that if value is not 1, then insert all of `'<tr>'+
      '<td> category </td>' +
      '<td> material </td>' +
      '<td> ups </td>' +
    '</tr>'`. It sees it all as one big string. Whereas if value is 1, then it inserts _only_ `'<tr style="background-color:ash">'` and nothing else. The rest is considered as the right-hand part of the `:`. You need to give the compiler clear instructions about which part is the changeable part, and which part is to be used in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use round brackets to specify what part of your conditional (ternary) `?` is added as the prefix:

`(value === 1 ? '<tr style="background-color:lime">' : '<tr>')+...`

At the moment you have it such that if the `value` is `1` it will append `<tr style="background-color:ash>` without the concatenated item. Thus, you can use brackets to specify that the concatenated item is added to the result of your ternary operator (`?`)

See example below: (note I changed background:ash to background:lime as ash isn't a valid css color name)

```js
function insertRow(value) {
  $('#invoiceTable').append(
    (value === 1 ? '<tr style="background-color:lime">' : '<tr>') +
    '<td> category </td>' +
    '<td> material </td>' +
    '<td> ups </td>' +
    '</tr>'
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="invoiceTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Material</th>
      <th>ups</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
</table>

<input type=button value='insert ash row' onclick='insertRow(1)' />

<input type=button value='insert white row' onclick='insertRow(0)' />
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is not returning any value. You can assign the value returned from the operator to a variable so that you can use it later.

**Please Note:** There is no such `background-color` value `ash`. Try some other value.

```js
function insertRow(value){
  var tr = value === 1 ? '<tr style="background-color:lightgray">' : '<tr>';
  $('#invoiceTable').append(
    tr +
      '<td> category </td>' +
      '<td> material </td>' +
      '<td> ups </td>' +
    '</tr>'
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="invoiceTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover" >
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Material</th>
          <th>ups</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
 
<input type=button value='insert ash row' onclick='insertRow(1)'/>

<input type=button value='insert white row' onclick='insertRow(0)'/>
```